# Sequelize bulk insert with associations

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, associations, bulkinsert

I'm trying to bulk insert with associations,
I have this 'Song' model which have one to many relationships with 'Genre' and 'Language' defined with the migrations CLI.
Song:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class Song extends Model {
     
        static associate(models) {
            // define association here
            Song.hasMany(models["Language"])
            Song.hasMany(models["Genre"])
        }
    };
    Song.init({
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        energy: {type: DataTypes.FLOAT, allowNull: false},
        valence: {type: DataTypes.FLOAT, allowNull: false}
    }, {
        sequelize,
        modelName: 'Song',
        timestamps: true
    });
    return Song;
};
```

Language:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class Language extends Model {
        static associate(models) {
            // define association here
            models["Language"].belongsTo(models["Song"])
        }
    };
    Language.init({
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        name: DataTypes.STRING
    }, {
        sequelize,
        modelName: 'Language',
        indexes: [{unique: true, fields: ['name']}]
    });
    return Language;
};
```

Genre:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class Genre extends Model {
        /**
         * Helper method for defining associations.
         * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
         * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
         */
        static associate(models) {
            // define association here
            models["Genre"].belongsTo(models["Song"])
        }
    };
    Genre.init({
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        name: DataTypes.STRING
    }, {
        sequelize,
        modelName: 'Genre',
        indexes: [{unique: true, fields: ['name']}]
    });
    return Genre;
};
```

I'm trying to bulk insert songs with languages and genres like this:

```
Song.bulkCreate(songs, {
    include: [Genre,Language]
}).then(() => {
    const result = {
        status: "ok",
        message: "Upload Successfully!",
    }
    res.json(result);
});
```

each song in the songs array is structured like this:

```
{
    name: "abc",
    genres: [{name: "abc"}],
    languages: [{name: "English"}],
    energy:  1,
    valence: 1
}
```

I'm ending up with a full songs table but genres and languages are empty
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Just in case anyone else got here from a search, starting from [version 5.14](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/releases/tag/v5.14.0)
Sequelize added the option to use `include option in bulkCreate` as follows:

```
await Song.bulkCreate(songsRecordsToCreate, {
    include: [Genre,Language]
})
```

Comment: And still they doesn't have this option described in the documentation (v5 and v6)

Answer (score 4):

**Edit 2nd Feb 2023**

As [none](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8978791/none) answered above, as of [v5.14.0](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/releases/tag/v5.14.0) the `include` option is now available on `bulkInsert`.

---

Unfortunately `bulkCreate` does not support `include` option like `create` do.
You should use `create` in a cycle inside a transaction.

```
const transaction = ...
for (const song of songs) {
  await Song.create(song, {
    include: [Genre,Language]
  }, { transaction })
}
await transaction.commit()
```

or you can use Promise.all to avoid using `for`.

Comment: This is not true anymore, starting from version 5.14 Sequelize added the option to use the include option in `bulkCreate`