# Sequelize bull create with a common id based on previous inserted data

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to insert the following data using sequelize and nodejs into my db

```
{
  "basicDetails": {
    "companyName": "demo",
    "email": "demo5@demo.com",
    "phone": "5019918819",
    "address": "manab",
    "pincode": "400078",
    "city": "Mumbai",
    "state": "Maharashtra"
  },
  "subOffices": [
    {
      "subofficename": "bpo",
      "location": "random"
    },
    {
      "subofficename": "fintech",
      "location": "worli"
    }
  ],
  "companyUsers": [
    {
      "userName": "Random user",
      "userEmail": "random@us.com",
      "userPhone": "0000000000"
    },
    {
      "userName": "Demo User",
      "userEmail": "demo@us.com",
      "userPhone": "1111111111"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have basically 3 tables :-

1. Client (id)
2. SubOffices (foreignKey is the client id)
3. CompanyUsers (foreignKey is the client id)

basic details would be stored in a client table and using the id of that data. I would like to insert the sub offices and company users in there respective table where foreign key would be the id that I get from inserting my basic details into the client table

I am able to insert the basic details to the client table and fetch the id of that data . I would further like to do a bulk insert using sequelize including the id that I am getting from the client data as a foreign key to it.

```
router.post("/addClient", async function (req, res) {
  const basicdetails = req.body.basicDetails;
  console.log(basicdetails);
  const subofficesData = [...req.body.subOffices];
  const companyusers = [...req.body.companyUsers];
  console.log("suboffices: " + suboffices);
  subofficesData.forEach((item) => console.log(item));
  companyusers.forEach((item) => console.log(item));

  const data = await client.create({
    companyName: basicdetails.companyName,
    email: basicdetails.email,
    mobileNumber: basicdetails.phone,
    address: basicdetails.address,
    pincode: basicdetails.pincode,
    city: basicdetails.city,
    state: basicdetails.state,
  });

  console.log(data.id);

  const subofficesResult = await suboffices.bulkCreate(subofficesData, {
    clientId: data.id,
  });
  console.log(subofficesResult);

  //   console.log(req.body.suboffices);
});
```

Comment: It is not clear from your description what your problem is, can you explain what the question is more clearly please

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have edited the question is it clear now

Comment: Not really, what is your problem that you are asking about

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have edited the question is it clear now

Comment: Check out the second answer in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63922261/sequelize-bulk-insert-with-associations

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't actually look like a scenario where you want to use bulkCreate at all.

Look into utilizing the include property in the options object of your create method.

https://sequelize.org/master/manual/creating-with-associations.html