# Sequelize bulkCreate with belongsTo (existing) model

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have two models: **Role** and **User**.

The relation between them is **Role has many Users** and **User belongs to Role**.

When I create individual users and then set the role it works. But when I try to bulk create users and have them assigned to specific role objects, it either leaves the foreign column null (without include ) or it tries to insert the role instead of associating the user with the already existing role.

**Is it possible to set belongsTo association within a bulkCreate array of objects, containing the associated model, instead of directly setting the ID?**

My models:

Role Model

```
class Role extends Model {

    static associate(models) {
        this.hasMany(models.User);
    }
}

Role.init({
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    level: DataTypes.SMALLINT.UNSIGNED,
    unrestricted: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    preferences: DataTypes.TEXT
}, {
    sequelize: getSequelizeInstance(),
    modelName: 'Role',
    timestamps: true
});
```

User Model

```
class User extends Model {

    static associate(models) {
        this.belongsTo(models.Role);
    }
}

User.init({
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    username: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: true
    },
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    refreshToken: DataTypes.STRING
}, {
    sequelize: getSequelizeInstance(),
    modelName: 'User',
    timestamps: true,
    scopes: {
        withoutSecrets: {
            attributes: { exclude: ['password', 'refreshToken'] },
        }
    }
});
```

Inserting data

Roles

```
await Role.bulkCreate([
    {
        name: 'Dev',
        level: 0,
        unrestricted: true
    },
    {
        name: 'Admin',
        level: 1,
        unrestricted: false
    },
    {
        name: 'User',
        level: 2,
        unrestricted: false
    },
]);
```

Users (This works!)

```
const roles = await Role.findAll();
const user = await User.create({
    name: 'Dev',
    username: 'dev',
    password: await hashPassword('123456')
});
await user.setRole(roles.find(role => role.dataValues.name === 'Dev'));
```

Users (This gives a validation error, query given below)

```
const roles = await Role.findAll();
await User.bulkCreate([
    {
        name: 'Dev',
        username: 'dev',
        password: await hashPassword('123456'),
        Role: roles.find(role => role.dataValues.name === 'Dev')
    },
    {
        name: 'Admin',
        username: 'admin',
        password: await hashPassword('123456'),
        Role: roles.find(role => role.dataValues.name === 'Admin')
    },
    {
        name: 'User',
        username: 'user',
        password: await hashPassword('123456'),
        Role: roles.find(role => role.dataValues.name === 'User')
    },
], {
    include: Role
});

Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `name`, `level`, `unrestricted`, `preferences`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Roles` AS `Role`;      
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `Roles` (`id`,`name`,`level`,`unrestricted`,`preferences`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (1,'Dev',0,true,NULL,'2023-03-27 19:01:22','2023-03-27 19:01:22'),(2,'Admin',1,false,NULL,'2023-03-27 19:01:22','2023-03-27 19:01:22'),(3,'User',2,false,NULL,'2023-03-27 19:01:22','2023-03-27 19:01:22');

ERROR: Validation error
```

Using versions `Node: 16.19.0, CLI: 6.6.0, ORM: 6.29.3`

Comment: Does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/69973681/2956135

Comment: No, the effect is the same. Without `include` it just ignores the association when creating.